# Open XML SDK 2.0 inserting PDF to Word

Tags: c#, pdf, openxml

has anyone tried to insert pdf document into word using open xml sdk 2.0 ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

With the SDK there is a tool called ***DocumentReflector*** (in folder *C:\Program Files\Open XML Format SDK\V2.0\tools*). This tool opens an existing OpenXML document and generates the code that will produce this document.

Now you can create a simple document in Word with an embedded PDF and open this document using DocumentReflector. The code generated can then be a base for your document creation process.